# Align colored numbers in table

Tags: horizontal-alignment, color, siunitx

How to align colored numbers in the last line with other numbers in the same column?[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5pt,text margin right=5pt} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}[hc]
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|} 
    \hline
    Constraint/N events&$K_{e2}$ & $K_{\mu2}(\mu \rightarrow e, \text{pol.})$& $K_{\mu2}(\mu \rightarrow e, \text{unpol.})$  \\ \hline \hline
  Total & \num{2477000} & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-number-alignment = right]|}{26791675} & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-number-alignment = right]|}{26785638} \\ \hline
     In geom. acceptance & \num{1395765} & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-number-alignment = right]|}{4971061} & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-number-alignment = right]|}{5530884} \\ \hline 
    $10 GeV<p<65GeV$ & \num{1250166} & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-number-alignment = right]|}{3942491} & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-number-alignment = right]|}{4531133} \\ \hline
    $M^{2}_{miss}(e)<0.01GeV$ & \textcolor{blue}{\num{1250166}} & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-number-alignment = right]|}{\textcolor{green}{1405}} & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-number-alignment = right]|}{\textcolor{red}{16355}} \\ \hline  
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `S` column type as intended:

In your case, convert the column specification to

```
\begin{tabular}{| l || S[table-format=7.0] | S[table-format=8.0] | S[table-format=8.0] |}
```

The `table-format` key is already a special key. In these case you could define before hand `\sisetup{table-figures-decimal}` and than just use the `table-figures-integer` key with `7`, `8` and `8` as its value respectively.

If you enclose the first row’s entries in braces (`{}`) you don't even need to `\multicolumn` them, `siunitx` detects this automatically and typesets these cells according to the `table-text-alignment` key (default to `center`).

The macro `\color` is also detected by `siunitx` and can be used to change the output. The mentioned `\highlight` macro is for the use in units (in the second (mandatory) argument to `\SI`, in the mandatory argument of `\si` and in the `s` column).

For various other color declarations, `siunitx` provides also the keys `color`, `unit-color`, `number-color` and `negative-color`.

---

I have also used the `\SI` macro to typeset the values and units in the left column (units shall be typeset upright and with the proper space between them and the preceding value). The `miss` seemed like a property of the `M` and not as the product of `m`, `e` and `s^2` which is the reason I used `amsmath`’s `\text` macro to typeset the subscript. The `N` in `N events` is probably a variable, it should be typeset as such and `$N$` should be used.

As Josep Wright notes, the key `group-four-digits` can be used to add the `group-separator` back between the thousands and the hundreds.

I have also added a version of the table with the help of `booktabs` (without the four-digit-grouping).

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2.5pt,text margin right=2.5pt} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}[hc]
 \centering\sisetup{group-four-digits = true}
  \begin{tabular}{|l||S[table-format=7.0]|S[table-format=8.0]|S[table-format=8.0]|}
    \hline
    Constraint/$N$~events                        & {$K_{e2}$}          & {$K_{\mu2}(\mu \rightarrow e, \text{pol.})$} & {$K_{\mu2}(\mu \rightarrow e, \text{unpol.})$} \\ \hline\hline
    Total                                        & 2477000             & 26791675                                     & 26785638                                       \\ \hline
    In geom.~acceptance                          & 1395765             & 4971061                                      & 5530884                                        \\ \hline
    $\SI{10}{\giga\eV}<p<\SI{65}{\giga\eV}$      & 1250166             & 3942491                                      & 4531133                                        \\ \hline
    $M^{2}_{\text{miss}}(e)<\SI{0.01}{\giga\eV}$ & \color{blue}1250166 & \color{green}1405                            & \color{red}16355                               \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[hc]
 \centering %\sisetup{group-four-digits = true}
  \begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=7.0] S[table-format=8.0] S[table-format=8.0]}
    \toprule
    Constraint/$N$~events                        & {$K_{e2}$}          & {$K_{\mu2}(\mu \rightarrow e, \text{pol.})$} & {$K_{\mu2}(\mu \rightarrow e, \text{unpol.})$} \\ \midrule
    Total                                        & 2477000             & 26791675                                     & 26785638                                       \\
    In geom.~acceptance                          & 1395765             & 4971061                                      & 5530884                                        \\
    $\SI{10}{\giga\eV}<p<\SI{65}{\giga\eV}$      & 1250166             & 3942491                                      & 4531133                                        \\
    $M^{2}_{\text{miss}}(e)<\SI{0.01}{\giga\eV}$ & \color{blue}1250166 & \color{green}1405                            & \color{red}16355                               \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The newly added space between the values and units in the first column adds too much horizontal space so that the table is wider than the page. Besides not using vertical lines or alter the cells with the `\SI` macros, `\tabcolsep` could be reduced with `\addtolength\tabcolsep{<negative length>}`.

Comment: Was 95% of the way through doing the same :-) I'd add `group-four-digits = true` as the `1405` is otherwise not quite 'right' with the much larger values above.

Comment: I also suspect it should be `$N$~events` (almost certainly a variable) and `geom.~acceptance` (spacing fix).

Comment: @JosephWright Isn't `geom.\@ acceptance` the proper usage? (In `(n)german` french spacing is used anyway so I usually don't need to take care of sth like that.) The `~` in `$N$~events` does not seem necessary (but is right in text) — I'm always ambivalent about four-digit grouping in tables.